# How can i draw animating path of an object in kineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I drew a rectangle with kinetic.js and animating it in a circular path. In each animation frame i reduce it's radius.

Now i want to draw the line of this rectangle's animating path. I am not sure how can i do it by kinetic.js. Please help!

My codes

```
var R = 150;
$(document).ready(function () {
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'red'
});
layer.add(rect);
stage.add(layer);

var centerX = stage.width() / 2;

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(

function (f) {
    var cX = stage.width() / 2;
    var cY = stage.height() / 2;
    R = R - 1 / 1000;
    var X = cX + R * Math.cos(f.time / 1000);
    var Y = cY + R * Math.sin(f.time / 1000);
    rect.setX(X);
    rect.setY(Y);
}, layer);
anim.start();
```

});

Here is the codes: http://jsfiddle.net/tanvirgeek/n8z8N/

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can draw line segments that follow the path of your rectangle:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Cbq2c/

[image]

**First** Create a Kinetic.Line that will trace the rectangle's path

```
var line=new Kinetic.Line({
    stroke:"blue"
});
layer.add(line);
```

**Second** When you generate a new XY in the animation loop, add that XY to the line's points

```
var points=line.getPoints();
points.push(X,Y);
line.setPoints(points);
```

**Important Warning!** This Kinetics animation loop develops an undesirable pausing "stagger".  This stagger is small in Chrome, noticeable in IE and horrible in FireFox.  This seems to be due to the Kinetic.Line being unable to smoothly add + draw thousands of changing points of data, so I instead recommend using regular html5 canvas and requestAnimationFrame to do your effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var line=new Kinetic.Line({
    points:[0,0,100,100],
    stroke:"blue",
    strokeWidth:2
});
layer.add(line);

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'red'
});
layer.add(rect);

var cx=stage.getWidth() / 2;
var cy=stage.getHeight()/2;

var R=100;
var A=0;
points=[];

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(
    function (f) {
        R = R - 1 / 100;
        A += Math.PI/180;
        var X = cx + R * Math.cos(A);
        var Y = cy + R * Math.sin(A);
        points.push(X,Y);
        line.setPoints(points);
        rect.setX(X);
        rect.setY(Y);
    }, 
layer);

anim.start();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I read your bio from your stackexchange profile. So inspiring. Salute!!